# issues importing a script

Tags: python, function, python-import

Hello i have been working on this simple script and i have run into some rather annoying problems that i can not fix myself with the def. and import function it just won't work. here is the main script

```
import time         # This part import the time module
import script2      # This part imports the second script

def main():
    print("This program is a calaulater have fun using it")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Hello",name)
    q1 = input("Would you like to some maths today? ")

if q1 == "yes":
    script2 test()

if q1 == "no":
    print("That is fine",name,"Hope to see you soon bye")
    time.sleep(2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(10)
```

And then the second script is called script2 here is that script as well
    import time

```
def test():
    print("You would like to do some maths i hear.")
    print("you have some truely wonderfull option please chooice form the list below.")
```

That is my script currently but it deos not work please help me.

Comment: What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: Try `script2.test()` instead of `script2 test()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your indentation doesn't seems to be right. As zvone stated. Secondly you should use script2.test() instead of script2 test(). A functional code is

```
import time         # This part import the time module
import script2      # This part imports the second script

def main():
    print("This program is a calaulater have fun using it")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Hello",name)
    q1 = input("Would you like to some maths today? ")

    if q1 == "yes":
        script2.test()

    if q1 == "no":
        print("That is fine",name,"Hope to see you soon bye")
        time.sleep(2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error:

```
def main():
    #...
    q1 = input("Would you like to some maths today? ")

if q1 == "yes":
    # ...
```

Firstly, the `q1` in `main()` and the `q1` outside are not the same variable.

Secondly, `if q1 == "yes":` is executed before `q1 = input(...)`, because `main()` was not called yet.

The solution would be to return the `q1` value from main and only then use it:

```
def main():
    # ...
    return q1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ...
    result_from_main = main()    
    if result_from_main == "yes":
       # ...
```

Of course, the all names are completely messed up now, but that is a different problem...